# Add CSS classes and repeating header to Visualforce PDF

Tags: visualforce, pdf, css

I have a Visualforce page that renders as a PDF. It displays a table of data and an image on the header on each page:

```
<apex:page renderAs="pdf">
  <head>
  <style type="text/css" media="print">
    @page {
      @top-center {
        content: element(header);
      }
    }

    div.header {
      position: running(header);
    }

    .sectionTitle {
      font-weight: bold;
    }
  </style>
  </head>

  <div class="header">
    <img src="{!$Resource.logo}" width="25%"/>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class="sectionTitle">test</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</apex:page>
```

My issue is that I want to apply CSS classes to my table elements; however the CSS is not applied (in this example the text should be bold but it doesn't). If I set the `applyBodyTag` or `applyHtmlTag` of `apex:page` to `false`, it does take effect the CSS classes for the table but the header breaks.

Any ideas?

Comment: When you say "the header breaks" what exactly do you mean?

Comment: @PhilHawthorn to explain that better please see the following gif:
http://cl.ly/ZQAQ

As you can see the header get's misplaced. Also the text overlaps the header.

Comment: Ok, got you. So, I don't think the header is broken as such - its just that by adding the `applyBodyTag="false"` you are getting it to recognise the CSS (whereas without it, it isn't), its that that is moving your logo right to the top (i'm a bit puzzled by why it appears to the left though). I've updated my answer to include the VF, note the addition of the `margin-top` styling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your `<apex:page>` to this:

```
<apex:page renderAs="pdf" applyBodyTag="false">
```

According to the [docs](http://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_compref_page.htm):

> A Boolean value that specifies whether or not Visualforce should
>   automatically add a `<body>` tag to the generated HTML output. Set to
>   false to disable adding the `<body>` tag to the response, for example,
>   when the  tag is statically set in your markup. If not
>   specified, this value defaults to the value of the applyHtmlTag
>   attribute if it's set, or true, if applyHtmlTag isn't set.

Using the sample you provided, I was able to render the following as PDF:

[image]

The header (logo) appears on every page as expected using the following VF:

```
<apex:page renderAs="PDF" applyBodyTag="false">
  <head>
  <style type="text/css" media="print">
    @page {
      margin-top: 1.5in;
      @top-center {
        content: element(header);
      }
    }
    div.header {
      position: running(header);
    }
    .sectionTitle {
      font-weight: bold;
    }
  </style>
  </head>
  <div class="header">
    <center><img src="{!$Resource.logo}" width="25%"/></center>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class="sectionTitle">test</td>
      </tr>
      <!--rest removed for brevity...-->
    </table>
  </div>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: As I mentioned, I tried that and indeed the CSS takes effect, but then the header breaks functionality

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read properly - let me take another look, i've done a lot of this type of thing

Comment: @jonathanwiesel Were you able to resolve this? I header is set properly on the first PDF page but on the next pages, the header and contents are getting overlapped. Any way to solve this?

Comment: @RajeshShah yes, the trick was involved using the `margin-top` property

Answer (score 2):

try adding the attribute standardStylesheets="false" or showHeader="false" and build your own header.

Comment: Already tried, no luck